# How to Send Multidimensional Json array through php cURL

Tags: php, json, curl, multidimensional-array

/*Unable to Send Multidimensional Json array through php cURL .
          so in the below code i send it as array of Objects  which will be difficult to   retrieve in     python*/

```
   $_api_url="http://example.com" ;
    $params = http_build_query(array('data_Details' => json_encode($request)));
    //initialize and setup the curl handler        
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);

    //execute request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

   //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the following example: [POSTing JSON Data With PHP cURL](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl)

Useful excerpt:

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://api.local/rest/users');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: @ammu Why? Which statement does not accept the multidimensional array? `json_encode()` is the only statement taking the array...

Comment: What is the error you receive from the code supplied?

Comment: if i use this code and $data_string is multidimensional array then response will be NULL

Comment: @ammu Nope... `$data_string` will be a string with a JSON-representation of a multidimensional array. I don't know who you are sending the request to, but ask them what they would like to receive and post this in the question... Without an error, I cannot help you any further.

Comment: The mistake was in checking the response   :                       In Response page: instead of this code...... echo $JSONData = file_get_contents("php://input");
exit();                                                                        firstly i used :.............echo json_decode($_POST);exit();

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_string = json_encode($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);
```

$request should be associated array format.